# Call method non-static with static in PHP

Tags: php

i have code look like this:

```
abstract class Object
{
    public static function __callStatic($name, $parameters)
    {
        $object = get_called_class();
        $object = new $object;
        if (method_exists($object, $name)) {
            return call_user_func_array(array($object, $name), $parameters);
        }
    }
}

class Log extends Object
{
    public function message($message)
    {
        echo 'Log: '.$message.'.<br>';
    }
}
```

now, i call:

```
Log::message('test');
```

this's result:

Strict standards: Non-static method Log::message() should not be called statically...

Log: test.

somebody can help me?

Comment: if you want to call `message` the way you did, just change `public function message($message)` to `public static function message($message)`

Comment: check your php version; the magic method `__callStatic()` is only available from 5.3.0

Answer (score 3):

`__callStatic` will work only if your method does not exist.
Rename your method from "message" to "messageStatic" and change `__callStatic` method:

```
 if (method_exists($object, $name.'Static')) {
    return call_user_func_array(array($object, $name.'Static'), $parameters);
}
```

Comment: Note: __callStatic will also work if the method is declared as protected.

Answer (score 1):

That's because [`__callStatic()`](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.callstatic) will be triggered only for non-existent methods while your `message()` method exists and it's non-static.

E.g `Log::foo('test');` won't trigger this message since there's no such method.

You're checking your method on existence inside `__callStatic()` and this *has no sense*: if `__callStatic()` was called, it's a call for non-existent method. Thus, condition will always be false and useless.

This may seems odd (because you may wish to call static method as non-static and create instance inside `__callStatic()`) - but from point of visibility, static and non-static methods *are same*: thus, if method exists as static it will also be visible as non-static.